# Object error when iterating through VUE v-for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for

Pardon, my lack of knowledge here. Still getting the hang of Vue. I am trying to iterate through a loop and keep running into an issue when my length is a hardcoded value. I keep getting:

`'"[Vue warn]: Error in render: 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined'`

Js:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    inputs: [],
    items: [
    { title: 'Blue' },
    { title: 'Yellow' },
    { title: 'Red' },
    { title: 'Purple' }
  ]
  }
})
```

Markup:

```
<div id="app">
 <ul>
  <li v-for="n in 4">
    <label>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        v-model="inputs"
        :value="n"
        :disabled="inputs.length > 0 && inputs.indexOf(n) === -1" 
        > Item {{ items[n].title }}
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-for="n in 4"` will mean that `n` is 1,2,3,4 - rather than 0,1,2,3. So it won't match with the indices of the array. You need to use the `index` of the loop counter, which is the second argument, i.e.

`<li v-for="(n, i) in 4">`

and then

`{{ items[i].title }}`

Comment: Or just `v-for="({ title }, n) in items"` and then use `title` and `n`.

Answer (score 0):

You made an incorrect loop... I don't know if the logics you made are correct, but this is how a vue js loop should be:

```
<li v-for="item in items">
    <label>
      <input :value="item"> 
      Item {{ item.title }}
    </label>
</li>
```

After this, perhaps your console will show an error saying that li tag misses a key, then, see the docs https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html :)